# Unable to earn any credits in StarCraft II campaign

Tags: starcraft-2

I am trying to play through the Wings of Liberty campaign and having fun, then randomly I start completing missions and noticed my credits was stuck at 25,000. No matter what missions I finish I never seem to get more credits. Is there something I'm missing, or is this a bug? The missions each say they have some reward like "120,000", which I assume is supposed to be earned credits (?). This started happening around mission 10-15. Playing on Normal, but played a few missions on Easy.

Answer (score 2):

Credits for a mission are only awarded the *first time* you complete the mission. There is no way to farm additional credits during a campaign, so you'll never be able to purchase everything.

The mission still shows the original reward when you replay it, but you won't get it a second time if you start the mission from the archive.

This includes when you replay it at higher difficulty, since the credit reward doesn't change between difficulties.

Comment: To clarify, I am not repeating missions, I am just playing through in order. I was getting credits for a while, then suddenly no new missions give credits. I am still progressing through the campaign and getting research points, but no credit reward for any new missions.

Comment: Might have figured out the problem: turns out the Starcraft II campaigns/saves are massively bugged out for Windows 11 users at the moment. Has to do with the local save folder permissions. I also have been getting a lot of "save failed" warnings, as well as forced updates every time I close the game, and crash back to my cloud save when I start a new campaign, apparently all related issues: https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/qta0cl/are_starcraft_2_hots_and_wol_campaigns_broken_for/, https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/sc2/t/wol-campaign-missions-not-awarding-credits/23678

Comment: @RyanWilmington That’s a good finding! You can write it as your own answer for anyone else looking for the solution.